# How do I change Jenkins Git plugin from using GIT_ASKPASS to .gitcredentials

Tags: git, jenkins

How do I change Jenkins Git plugin from using GIT_ASKPASS to .gitcredentials

I've posted this question already:

[Jenkins cannot read Github password since upgrading to Git client plugin 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464130)

In short I have cloned my production instance of Jenkins 1.650 and upgraded the cloned instance to 2.25 on Windows 2012.

As part of this the Git Client plugin was upgraded from 1.19.6 to 2.1.0 and now it cannot authenticate.

I have jobs which run perfectly if I downgrade this plugin again, but when running them using the upgraded plugin the jobs fail.

I have now noticed that the one difference I can see is that in the job output, on the instance where it works there is a message `using .gitcredentials to set credentials` and on the cloned instance `using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials`.

I suspect this is the issue or is at least related but I cannot find a way to change this.  Full output of failing jobs below:

```
08:18:40 Cloning the remote Git repository
08:18:40 Cloning repository https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git
08:18:40  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project # timeout=10
08:18:40 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git
08:18:40  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
08:18:40 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
08:18:40  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
08:18:41 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
08:18:41 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
08:18:41 stdout: 
08:18:41 stderr: '*dds23' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
08:18:41 operable program or batch file.
08:18:41 error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Windows\TEMP\pass6274847349411211542.bat'
08:18:41 bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
08:18:41 error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
08:18:41 fatal: could not read Password for 'https://user@github.com': No error
08:18:41 
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1745)
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1489)
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:512)
08:18:41    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1054)
08:18:41    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
08:18:41    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
08:18:41    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
08:18:41    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:401)
08:18:41 ERROR: null
08:18:41 Archiving artifacts
08:18:41 [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
08:18:41 [htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project\server.project\server.distribution\target\htmldocs\documentation to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\project\htmlreports\documentation
08:18:41 ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project\server.project\server.distribution\target\htmldocs\documentation' does not exist.
08:18:41 [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
08:18:41 [BFA] No failure causes found
08:18:41 [BFA] Done. 0s
08:18:41 Started calculate disk usage of build
08:18:41 Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
08:18:41 Started calculate disk usage of workspace
08:18:41 Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
08:18:42 Sending e-mails to: bob@yeah
08:18:43 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Could possibly be to do with Git Credential Manager for Windows? Try uninstalling the Git on the machine the job runs on, and reinstall without the credential manager (there should be an option to deselect)

Comment: Tried that, but still using GIT_ASKPASS unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered by a serverfault user:

https://serverfault.com/questions/823152/how-do-i-change-jenkins-git-plugin-from-using-git-askpass-to-gitcredentials

However in short there are known bugs with Jenkins 2+ in a Windows environment with reading passwords which contains a character which requires Windows escaping in the command prompt.

I changed the password for the Github account and this resolved the authentication issue.